# Strange date issue with handlbars date format helper,

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a data set where each record includes various date fields.  The following key value pairs, each in their own record all the same 'level' within the file are some examples of the data and the values (full file is 18k lines)

```
          "date_completed": null,
          "date_due": null,
          "date_modification": 1580895144,
          "date_started": null,
          "date_moved": 1580895144,
          "date_board": 0,
...
          "date_creation": 1580317329,
          "date_completed": null,
          "date_due": null,
          "date_modification": 1580895149,
          "date_started": null,
          "date_moved": 1580895149,
          "date_board": 0,
...
          "date_creation": 1580317329,
          "date_completed": null,
          "date_due": 0,
          "date_modification": 1580895131,
          "date_started": 0,
          "date_moved": 1580895131,
etc
```

An extract from my handlebars template looks like this:

```
 <div title="Creation Due" class="task-start-date text-right mb-1">
        {{#if date_creation}}
        <i class="fa fa-calendar">Created:</i> {{dtfmt date_creation}}
        {{/if}}

    </div>

    <div title="Modification Date" class="task-start-date text-right mb-1">
        {{#if date_modification}}
        <i class="fa fa-calendar">ModifieD:</i> {{dtfmt date_modification}}
        {{/if}}

    </div>

    <div title="Date Due" class="task-due-date text-right mb-1">
        {{#if date_due}}
        <i class="fa fa-calendar">Due:</i> {{dtfmt date_due}}
        {{/if}}
    </div>
```

My understanding is that it creates a div for each date and if the date entry for that record exists it prefixes it with an italics label followed by a formatted date based on the timestamp.

Everything works fine.  I can use any date date field in any position and it creates a valid page with lots of divs for each record showing all the dates etc...

UNLESS I try to use `date_modification`

When I do this I get nothing output at all.

I've tried just the raw time stamp by using `{{date_modification}}` and this appears to work fine.

I've tried formatting the time stamp by using `{{formatDate date_modification "YYYY"}}` and this fails too.

I've extracted all the timestamps and sorted to look for outliers/errors but all timestamps are integers in the range 1511784294 to 1682333294 with nothing looking odd.

I've updated the version of handlebars to 4.7.7 but that made no difference.

This is someone else's code that I'm trying to modify to add dates to the output

I've used handlebars for the last 2-3 hours ;-)

I've searched the js that calls the handlebars template to see if it refers to the modification date stamp and processes it differently but can't see anything.

I seem to be able to do everything with it except

Any clues on where I should start looking would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That is a strange issue indeed :) what happens when you create a new test file where you copy just a few (<10) records from the original, does it fail for that too? And if you change the name of the field?

Comment: Could one of the `date_modification` values be invalid and causing an Error?

Comment: I took the input file down to one record and there was still an error.
I copied a known working date from one of the other date fields into the date_modification field and there was still the error.

What I don't know is how to see errors, to work out why its not displaying anything.  All i see is a blank page. There is nothing in the console log and I don't know if there is a debug mode in handlebars and if there is how to enable it.